# How to create a binary variable for logistic regression by using key words in text variable

Tags: r, text, nlp

I have criminal sentencing data that contains a text variable which contains phrases like "2 months jail", "14 months prison", "12 months community supervision." I would like to run a logistic regression to determine the odds that a particular defendant is sent to prison or jail, or if they were released to community supervision. So I want to create a binary variable that shows a 1 for someone sent to "jail"/"prison" and a 0 for those sent to another program

I have tried using `library(qdap)` but have not had any luck. I have also tried `ifelse(df$text %in% "jail", "1", "0")` but it only shows 1 observation when I know there are several thousand.

Small data sample:

```
data<-data.frame('caseid'=c(1,2,3),'text'=c("went to prison","went to jail","released"))

  caseid           text
1      1 went to prison
2      2   went to jail
3      3       released
```

Trying to create a binary variable - `sentenced` - to analyze logistically like:

```
  caseid           text sentenced
1      1 went to prison         1
2      2   went to jail         1
3      3       released         0
```

Thank you for any help you can offer!

Comment: Maurits' answer is correct, but be aware the transform function uses nonstandard evaluation, which can get tricky in certain situations. A more common approach would be: data$sentenced <- as.integer(grepl("jail|prison", data$text))

Comment: @BillO'Brien `transform` doesn't use NSE. It evaluates an argument within the environment of the object to be transformed. That's different from how e.g. `dplyr::mutate` works. So `transform(data, ...)` is standard evaluation of `...`, within the environment of `data`.

Comment: I stand corrected ;) I misinterpreted a warning in the docs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the following in base R

```
transform(data, sentenced = +grepl("(jail|prison)", text))
#  caseid           text sentenced
#1      1 went to prison         1
#2      2   went to jail         1
#3      3       released         0
```

Explanation: `"(jail|prison)"` matches `"jail"` or `"prison"`, and the unary operator `+` turns the output of `grepl` into an `integer`.